# Opening JavaScript code with node.js in Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I'm just starting to learn JavaScript, and am already stuck with this basic exercise. I've written some basic script that writes "Hello World" to the console, and I'm trying to use node.js to execute the file "index.js" in Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal, but instead of executing the script, it returns "ReferenceError: index is not defined". If it helps, the contents of index.js are as follows:

```
console.log('Hello World');
```

Comment: Where is `index.js` located in your files, and where are you when you try to execute the script?  (ie, what does `pwd` or the `node` equivalent give you, whatever that is?)

Comment: what command are you using to execute your index.js? Also, which terminal shell is being launched by vscode (cmd, node, bash, powershell, etc.)?

Comment: I'm not sure how to tell which terminal shell is being used, where can I find that out? *edit* Never mind, I see it states it right at the top, Windows Powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running node.js, and then typing `index.js` at the REPL.

This causes node to try to interpret what you are typing as JavaScript. It does not cause it to try to run the JS in the file called `index.js`.

It tries to read the variable `index` (which you haven't defined) and then access the `.js` property on that object.

---

You need to either:

- Specify the JS to run *at the time you start Node.js* by typing `node index.js`
- `require("./index")`

Comment: I don't know what REPL is.

Comment: But the rest of it worked! I just had to kill the terminal to restart with `node index.js`. Thank you!